# Automation of webbrowser using watir and ruby

Tags: ruby, automation, browser, watir

I have installed ruby 1.9.2 and watir on my windows 7 system. Now I want to automate my web browser. Suppose there are 10 different links which I want my browser to browse after certain amount of time. How do I do this? I am new to ruby and watir. Can someone suggest me how the process of coding would be or suggest me a site or an ebook where I can get material regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a lot of the basics of scripting (conditional logic, loops, waiting, etc) are relative to the basic Ruby language and not the specific classes and methods implemented by Watir, I'd suggest starting off with a good book on scripting with Ruby.

My favorite is by one of the original folks responsible for Watir itself, Brian Marick  "[Everyday Scripting with Ruby: for Teams, Testers, and You](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0977616614)".

In terms of watir, there's the tutorials in the [Watir wiki](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Start+Here), and the book that Zelkjo is working on.

The thing you describe, is 90% scripting (repeating a given type of action, with a different input, after a specified time interval) and 10% watir (navigating to the link value), so I'd start with the scripting stuff first.

For someone on a budget, I would also offer the following "free" books  *(I put 'free' in quotes because I'm familiar with all the time and effort that goes into authoring a book, and these are not 'free'. They come at the expense of a lot of blood, sweat and tears on the part of authors/editors etc. who have then been generous enough to then offer up their work without pay.  I think calling them 'free' devalues the labor that went into creating them.)*

- ["Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmers Guide"](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) is often installed by the Ruby installer (depending on version) or can be accessed at the link above.  I've used this more as a reference than a learning tool, but it might work for you.
- Why’s (Poignant) Guide to Ruby, available in both [HTML](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/) and [PDF](http://www.ember.co.nz/files/resources/whys-poignant-guide-to-ruby.pdf) versions, is somewhat iconic in the Ruby community.  I found the writing style amusing and got some good stuff out it it, but then I'v been programming in a variety of languages since the days of teletypes and 110baud acoustically coupled modems.
- [Mr. Neighborly’s Humble Little Ruby Book](http://humblelittlerubybook.com/) -  I've not read this one, but it seems well regarded if a tiny bit out of date.  [Aaron Sumner](http://everydayrails.com/2010/07/28/free-ruby-rails-books.html) said of it "*it’s relatively short (under 150 pages) and in a very friendly, accessible tone. If you’re still getting familiar with the Ruby language itself, it’s as good an introduction as there is out there."*

All of those are I think more geared to someone who already understands programming, and not as good for a new tester starting out doing automation. For that you'd be better served spending the money for Marik's book, Since he's worked as a tester, and understands testing, and the book is largely aimed at testers, I thus think you can get far more out of it.  Seriously it may not be free, but consider it an investment in your education and career.

Comment: the book you suggested for ruby "Everyday Scripting with ruby: for Team, Testers, and You" is not free. Can u give recommend some freely available material on the net. Thanx a lot for your support by the way.

Comment: OK, well personally I figure that if an author worked hard on a book and I get something out of it, it's only fair to pay them for it.  However there are some who have been generous enough to make their work available for free. I've modified the answer and added links to three of them. I don't think they are as good for someone in your situation, but if you can't afford to, or are too cheap to, buy books they are what's available that's worth the time to read.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you browser Watir web site: http://watir.com/

I have also started writing a book (current version is 0.6):

https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook
https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/downloads

Comment: I really appreciate that Zeljko has been making early versions of his book free as the work progresses.  On his behalf I would ask that anyone reading it take the time to give him feedback on both what is working well for you, and what you feel needs work.  Taking the time to provide such feedback is only a fair 'payback' for what you are getting by being able to read it for no cost but your time. It's a small thing perhaps, but only reasonable in view of the effort he is putting into creating the book in the first place.